# Determine for which $a$ it holds that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x-y|^{a-1}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a>0$.

Determine for which values of $a$ it holds that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x-y|^{a-1}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$

The solution indicated is $a>3$.

Passing in polar coordinates, I obtain:

$$\frac{|x-y|^{a-1}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\rho^{a-3}|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|^{a-1}}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}$$

If $a > 3$, when $\rho \to 0$, the fraction goes to $0$, and this does not depend on $\theta$.

However, this is not enough for the limit to exist and it must exist a $g(\rho)$ such that:

$$\frac{\rho^{a-3}|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|^{a-1}}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}\leqslant g(\rho)\to 0 $$

But

$$\frac{|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|^{a-1}}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}$$

is not limited, because, for example, when $\theta \to \pm \frac{3}{4}\pi$, it goes to $\mp \infty$.

Where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct that $a=3$ will not work, just take the path $y=-x+x^2$. In fact there is no $a$ you could choose that would fix this, as for any $a>3$ the path $y = -x+x^{a-1}$ will lead to a limit that doesn't exist. ($a<3$ fails already from the polar coordinates)

Comment: I should have written that the solution indicated is $a>3$, not just $3$.

However, the substance does not change, the result indicated is still wrong, since the limit does not exist whatever the choice of $a$.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you obtain the upper bound?

Comment: I was wrong, now I should have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Determine for which values of $\;a\;$ it holds that:
> $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x-y|^{a-1}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0\;.$$

By letting $\;X=x-y\;$ and $\;Y=x+y\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x-y|^{a-1}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt2\;|X|^{a-1}}{Y\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\;.$

**First case** : $\;a\le1\;.$

$\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt2\;|X|^{a-1}}{Y\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt2}{Y|X|^{1-a}\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\;,$

but the last limit does not exist because we get different results when we calculate the limits of the restrictions of the function to two different subsets of its domain, indeed

$\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y>0\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2}{Y|X|^{1-a}\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=$

$=\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y>0\end{align}}\dfrac1{Y|X|^{1-a}}$$\cdot\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y>0\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=$

$=+\infty\cdot(+\infty)=+\infty\;,$

$\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y<0\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2}{Y|X|^{1-a}\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=$

$=\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y<0\end{align}}\dfrac1{Y|X|^{1-a}}$$\cdot\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y<0\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=$

$=-\infty\cdot(+\infty)=-\infty\;.$

**Second case** : $\;a>1\;.$

The limit $\;\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt2\;|X|^{a-1}}{Y\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\;$ does not exist because we get different results when we calculate the limits of the restrictions of the function to two different subsets of its domain, indeed

$\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&X=0\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2\;|X|^{a-1}}{Y\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=$$\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&X=0\end{align}}\dfrac0{Y\big|Y\big|}=0\;,$

$\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y=|X|^{a-1}\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2\;|X|^{a-1}}{Y\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=$

$=\lim\limits_{\begin{align}(X,&Y)\to(0,0)\\&Y=|X|^{a-1}\end{align}}\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{X^2+X^{2(a-1)}}}=+\infty\;.$

**Conclusion** :

In any case, for any $\;a\in\mathbb{R}\;,$ the limit

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|x-y|^{a-1}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt2\;|X|^{a-1}}{Y\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$

does not exist.